# Integer String Initial Population in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to create a GA population of integers in MATLAB, where each individual is a string of random numbers `1-8`, without repeating any number.
I know the following creates a random arrangement of numbers `1 -8`:

```
A = randperm(8)
```

I would like to know how to create a function that creates a population of such a kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) [used to work](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/25354) was with `sort` and `rand`. We can do it the same way, but with multiple columns to get a population:

```
>> N = 8;  % length of random string
>> P = 10; % population
>> [~,AA]=sort(rand(N,P))
AA =
     5     6     7     6     1     4     7     8     3     2
     8     7     6     5     4     2     4     3     2     3
     6     3     1     8     8     5     8     1     5     8
     3     4     8     1     7     6     2     7     4     7
     4     2     5     4     6     1     1     4     1     4
     2     5     2     3     3     8     3     6     6     6
     1     1     3     2     2     3     6     5     8     1
     7     8     4     7     5     7     5     2     7     5
```

Comment: The individual string (i.e a single row) is the one that should have an arrangement of the numbers 1 to 8. This is because each row would represent an arrangement of facilities in a layout. If you could help me develop such i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Kandwe Each column in the above is what you are after. If you want that on rows, then your answer is the transpose (`AA'`).